# Javascript error in syntax?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to write a function that makes all links execute a function on click, but I have NO idea why this isn't working:

```
function interceptLinks() {
    var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length
    for (i=0; i<numLinks; i++) {
        if ls[i].onclick {
            //Don't do anything, cause there's already code there!
        }
        else {
            ls[i].onclick = "reloadInfo();";
        }
    }
}
```

It just throws a "interceptLinks is not defined" error when I run the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses around your `if` condition:

```
        if (ls[i].onclick) {
```

That's all. The error "interceptLinks is not defined" that you get when trying to run the function shouldn't be the first error you see. When you include/compile the function in the first place you'll get a syntax error ("unexpected identifier" or something of the sort). That's the error you need to resolve; don't worry about the *next* error until it's dealt with.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I KNEW there was something wrong, I just couldn't find it. I TOTALLY forgot about the brackets. Thanks! :D

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Comment: @VisioN Vote cast, cheers! (I saw that post and plan to participate. It never occurred to me to ask answerers to contribute votes. Good idea, it'll probably get the message across more clearly.)